# How migrate MS Access database to Azure

Tags: ms-access, azure, migration

I am a MS Access database developer and am interested in learning how to migrate an Access database to Azure. I do have a MS 365 Enterprise E3 account so hopefully I'm on the right track to start with.  I have tried to migrate to MS Azure via Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access but have had no luck.  I'm sure I must be doing something wrong.  Can someone perhaps provide step-by-step instruction to guide me through the process?

Any help would certainly be appreciated.

These are the steps I have executed with no luck so far:

1) Launched Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access 32-bit.  (I tried the 64 bit also).

2) Clicked [Next] when the wizard appeared.

3) Under Create New Project I entered: Name = SqlMigration28 (because of all the failed attempts), Location = C:\Users\Steve\Documents\SSMAProjects, Migrate to = SQL Azure.

4) Clicked [Next].

5) Clicked [Add Databases] and navigated to my Access database file.

6) When it appeared in the window I clicked [Next].

7) In Select Objects to Migrate I clicked the tables only.

8) Clicked [Next].

9) Entered the server name .database.windows.net

10) The database that I had selected showed up in the Database field. Entered my user name and password.

11) Clicked [Next].

12) The link tables window appeared and I clicked on the checkbox.

13) Clicked [Next].

14) Got a conversion error message like I always do.  "There is nothing to process".

--Steve

Comment: I am sorry this is not working for you. SSMA does offer free customer support, so please forward this issue to the ssmahelp@microsoft.com alias.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue last evening. it appears if you have something already running on Azure db it will generate this error. I would recommend - create a new azure db and start the process again.

Answer (score -2):

I set up an Azure account and a database there then using SSMS I imported tables from an already built MS Access back-end into the Azure db. The import process was not flawless as you think it might be considering that both Azure and Access are Microsoft products.  Right-click on the Azure database>Tasks>Import Data then a lot of rigmarole to get the primary key and autonumber fields to work.

I could not get the migration assistant to work either.